# iexplorer under wine is missing wine-gecko

Tags: wine, 20.10

I'm not quite sure when it happened but a package for `wine-gecko` is no longer installed (I'm at Ubuntu 20.10).

This means that the Wine Internet Explorer, which uses a Gecko engine, will no longer work.

There is no error displayed on the app, but if you run it from a console the will be error messages displayed that mention the fact that Gecko is missing.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Ubuntu 20.10 also and I was getting the message:

> winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path...

I tried [the solution of Gustavo Carreno](https://askubuntu.com/a/1290790/855322) by downloading, extracting and copying the 32 bit package and also removing it and trying with the 64 bit package, but I was still getting the same message.

After some trials I found the solution for my case which is given in the following steps:

- I downloaded the latest 64 bit of Gecko from https://wiki.winehq.org/Gecko :

```
  $ wget http://dl.winehq.org/wine/wine-gecko/2.47.1/wine-gecko-2.47.1-x86_64.msi
```

- Ran the following:

```
  $ wine msiexec /i wine-gecko-2.47.1-x86_64.msi
```

- The installation added the following directory underneath my ***home*** directory:

```
  $ ls -l /home/_myuser_/.wine/drive_c/windows/system32/gecko/2.47.1/
  wine_gecko
```

- Now, Internet Explorer (when run using the `wine64 iexplore.exe` command) displays the web pages correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It took some Googling but I finally was able to solve this issue:

1. Download the `*.tar.bz2` with the latest version as listed under https://wiki.winehq.org/Gecko
2. Uncompress the contents somewhere
3. Move the uncompressed folder to `/usr/share/wine` renaming it `gecko`
4. To be clear on point 3: `mv /path/to/umcompressed/folder /usr/share/wine/gecko`

I've also read some pages that say that when you create a new prefix `wine` asks if you want to download gecko (and maybe mono, not sure), but I've added prefixes manually and with `winetricks` and never got asked to download `wine-gecko`.

**EDIT**

I've now realized that this worked on a machine that had wine installed since Ubuntu 19.04 or older but not with a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.10.

I'm still baffled at how this even worked in that one machine.

The [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1290790/160) provided by @FedonKadifeli is the accurate way to do it.

That is:

1. Download the `*.msi` files from https://wiki.winehq.org/Gecko
2. Run `wine msiexec /i wine-gecko-{version}-{arch}.msi`